# How do I get a random value from each column in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, each, multiple-columns

I have a three columns array and need to get one random value from the first column, one from the second and one from the third. Can you help me?

Comment: What have you done? Show your codes.

Comment: Is it a json array? You need to be more specific, best to show what you have so far.

Comment: @MladenOršolić JSON is a way to convert an array or object into a string so it can be sent over the network or put in a file. It's irrelevant when you're processing the array in code.

Comment: "way to convert" is called serialization yes, one of the tags was javascript, and there was no code provided. I also havent asumed but asked, as question is lacking in details and its potentially an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
var yourArray = [
   [0,3,6],
   [3,3,65],
   [3,5,1],
];
var c = yourArray.length - 1;
var rand = [];
rand[0] = yourArray[ Math.round(Math.random() * c) ][0];
rand[1] = yourArray[ Math.round(Math.random() * c) ][1];
rand[2] = yourArray[ Math.round(Math.random() * c) ][2];
```

Comment: @shabunc The question says "I have a 3 column array". So it's a given that all rows have the same number of elements.

Comment: deathyvs has changed question :)

Comment: @non it's me how had edited the question, if OP still insists that items should be of the same length, this could be easily added.

Comment: @shabunc You changed the question to match your answer, that's not fair!

Comment: @Barmar nope! I'll leave a comment to the author and will put on hold my answer till it will be clarified! Now I'm rolling back the edit.

Comment: Additional explanation would improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**The basics. How to get random value for each row**

It is unclear from the author's question whether he meand columns

Here's vanilla js approach.

```
// picking random value from an array;
var sample = function (arr) {
       return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]
}

return youArray.map(randomValue);
```

Personally I'd go with specific library that do this job for you. For instance, in lodash you can invoke `_.sample` method [which](https://lodash.com/docs#sample) "Gets a random element or n random elements from a collection".

In lodash your code can look like:

```
var samples = _.map(youArray, _.sample); // now you can use samples[0], samples[1] etc.
```

**How to get random value for each column**

To sample columns (if it indeed you intention, it's not that clear from the question to be honest) you need one additional step - get nth column.
Here's how to do it in pure js:

```
var column = function(arr, i) {
      return arr.map(function(it){return it[i];})
   } 

arr.map(function(it, i, a) {
    return sample(column(a,i));
});
```

Comment: You're getting a random element from each row, not each column.

Comment: @Barmar - [[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]] - please, clarify what is row and what is column in this context in your understanding.

Comment: `[a,b,c]` is the first row. `a, d, g` are in the first column.

Comment: When you enter an array as in @non's answer, rows are horizontal, columns are vertical.

Comment: @Barmar has edited the answer and rolled back the question )